# Algorithm for DAG with weighted vertices

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

Let G = (V,E) be a DAG (directed acyclic graph). Each vertex v has a weight w(v) assigned to it. Given a vertex u, let f(u) = max{w(v) where v can reach u}. So, in other words, f(u) is the maximum weight among the weights of all vertices that can reach u. The goal is to write a *linear time* algorithm that computes f(u) for every vertex u in G.

For example, let this be the input graph:

[image: graph]

Then the algorithm should compute the following:

- f(A) = 5
- f(B) = 12
- f(C) = 15
- f(D) = 12
- f(E) = 12

Accomplishing this in O(n(n+m)) time is straightforward, but how can this be done in O(n+m) time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a topological sort, then go through the nodes in this order and assign each node the max of the weight of itself and the `f` of the immediate predecessors (i.e. nodes that have an edge leading to the current node).

Comment: Alright, one possible topological sort for the example graph is E, A, B, D, C. Then based on what you're saying: E is assigned weight 12, since it doesn't have any predecessors. Next, A is assigned the max of its own weight (5) and the weight of its immediate predecessor (12), which is 12. However, this is incorrect because E can't reach A. Sorry if I'm misinterpreting what you're saying...

Comment: I meant "immediate predecessor" in the sense that there is an edge between the nodes. So A does not have predecessors.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense now. Thanks!